# Ignoring Categorical Data in Correlations in R

Tags: r, correlation

If I have a data set that has a mixture of numeric and categorical data, is there an easy way, in R, to compute the pair correlations but just ignore the categorical data for that computation?  Currently, I get an error if I try to compute correlations using `cor`

Answer (score 1):

Off topic, but check this answer.

```
d=ggplot2::diamonds
cor(d[,sapply(d,is.numeric)])
```

The key is us a Boolean vector for selecting columns.